# Must a workbox built sw.js be registered with ServiceWorkerModule in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I'm a little confused about Angular's role in registering a service worker using the `ServiceWorkerModule` found in `@angular/service-worker`. I have a separate folder in the root of my project in which I build a `service-worker.template.js` into `service-worker.js` using webpack. My built `service-worker.js` gets renamed and moved to `dist/sw.js`, and I'm serving `dist` with http-server to make sure my service worker is picked up by the browser.

I notice that Angular has a way of building a service worker from an `ngsw-config.json`. I'm not taking this approach, and instead I am building my service worker without Angular and registering it in `main.ts`. Do I need to register a service worker in Angular using the `ServiceWorkerModule` in this case? It was my understanding that since the service worker was already registered in `main.ts` that any XMLHttpRequest sent from my Angular app via the `HttpClient` would pass through my service worker. It appears that my service worker is not matching and caching calls to my API, and I wasn't sure if this was because I wasn't registering my service worker in `app.module.ts`.

I am registering my service worker in `main.ts`:

```
/**
 * If supported by the browser, loads and registers
 * the service worker using Workbox.
 */
function loadServiceWorker() {
  // If service workers are supported by this browser
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // Load our service worker javascript file
    const workbox = new Workbox('/sw.js');

    // Create a new workbox event listener to listen for when SWs are activated
    workbox.addEventListener('activated', async event => {
      // If this event is not an update to the service worker (new install)
      if (! event.isUpdate) {
        // Send an internal message to workbox to take control of this client
        workbox.messageSW({ type: 'CLIENTS_CLAIM' });
      }
    });

    // Register the service worker
    workbox.register();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service worker does not need to be registered in `app.module.ts` if you are already registering your service worker (as I am in `main.ts`). The issue I was experiencing was due to RegEx in my service worker not matching calls to my API.